# How to generate event transitions from time series data

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have clickhouse table which stores events data in timeseries format. It looks like the following

```
userid, stepNameId, ts 
u1, s1, t1
u1, s2, t2
u1, s3,t3
u1, s1,t4

u2, s1, t1
u2, s2, t2
u2, s3, t3
u2, s1, t4
```

I would like to query this table into generating timeline of events like the following

```
userid, prevstepNameId,  curstepNameId, ts
u1, s1, s2,t2
u1,s2,s3,t3
u1,s3,s1,t4

u2, s1, s2,t2
u2,s2,s3,t3
u2,s3,s1,t4
```

I could write a python script to do this. But I am wondering, if there is a way to do this within sql itself. Currently all this data is stored in clickhouse.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using window functions:

```sql
SELECT userid, steps[1] AS prevstepNameId, steps[2] AS curstepNameId, ts
FROM (
  SELECT
      userid,
      /* first_value(stepNameId) OVER w AS prevstepNameId, */
      /* last_value(stepNameId) OVER w AS curstepNameId, */
      groupArray(stepNameId) OVER w AS steps,
      ts
  FROM
  (
      /* test dataset */
      SELECT
          data.1 AS userid,
          data.2 AS stepNameId,
          data.3 AS ts
      FROM
      (
          SELECT arrayJoin([
            (1, 's1', now() + 1), (1, 's2', now() + 2), (1, 's3', now() + 3), (1, 's1', now() + 4), 
            (2, 's1', now() + 5), (2, 's2', now() + 6), (2, 's3', now() + 7), (2, 's1', now() + 8)]) AS data
      )
  )
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY ts ASC Range BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  )
WHERE length(steps) > 1;

/*
┌─userid─┬─prevstepNameId─┬─curstepNameId─┬──────────────────ts─┐
│      1 │ s1             │ s2            │ 2022-11-19 18:49:05 │
│      1 │ s2             │ s3            │ 2022-11-19 18:49:06 │
│      1 │ s3             │ s1            │ 2022-11-19 18:49:07 │
│      2 │ s1             │ s2            │ 2022-11-19 18:49:09 │
│      2 │ s2             │ s3            │ 2022-11-19 18:49:10 │
│      2 │ s3             │ s1            │ 2022-11-19 18:49:11 │
└────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────┘
*/
```

See for details:

- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/
- https://altinity.com/blog/tag/window-functions/
- https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-window-functions-current-state-of-the-art.